# Facebook advertisement appears all the time due to a JavaScript error

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, facebook.stackoverflow

The new Facebook ad on [Facebook Stack Overflow](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) appears on every single page load. A quick inspection with [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) shows that [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) is not included where the cookie check is being done:

```
$ is not defined    

if ($.cookie('fb_no_thx') || StackExchange.options.user.isRegistered) {

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8861004/xfbml-facebook-like-button-customising-the-add-comment-text-input (line 207)
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Firebug screenshot]

Also, this is the advertisement I'm talking about:
[image: Facebook advertisement]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about the Facebook mini-site for Stack Overflow, which no longer exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JavaScript error has now been fixed - crisis averted... This was related to our favorite issue - caching.